# Solving an exponential inequality in two ways

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, homework

I would like to solve the following inequality `E^x/x^1000 >= 2` without `Reduce`.
Then I would like to solve it with `Reduce` as well.

I have tried:

```
NSolve[ E^x/x^1000 - 2 >= 0]
```

but it's not giving me a value. Am I setting it up wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is **equivalent to investigating the behavior of the following function**

```
f[x_]:= Exp[x]/x^1000 -2
```

namely we are to **find subsection of its domaim, where `f` is positive**. One implicitly assumes that we are interested in real numbers, nevertheless one should exclude `x == 0` since this point does not belong to the domain of `f`, `FunctionDomain[f[x], x]`.
Let's sketch its plot for small absolute values,

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -2.3, 2.3}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {-2.2, 3.6}] // Quiet
```

[image]

It is hard to visualize the function `f` for `-1 < x <1`, it is continuous and takes finite values but blows up when we approach `x == 0`. Nonetheless we can observe that:

```
Limit[ f[x], x -> #] & /@ { -∞, 0,  ∞}
```

> ```
> { -2,  ∞,  ∞}
> ```

**I.  No Reduce**

**Continuinty of `f` implies that threre are two roots for positive `x`, and one for negative**,  since

```
{f[-1], f[2]} // N
```

> ```
>  {-1.63212, -2.}
> ```

More precisely there must be a root of `f` for `-1 < x < 0`, another for `0 < x < 2` as well as `2 < x`

using `NSolve` we can find

```
NSolve[f[x] == 0 && -1 < x < 0, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -0.99831}}
> ```

```
 NSolve[f[x] == 0 && 0 < x, x]
```

> ```
>  {{x -> 1.00031}, {x -> 9118.78}}
> ```

That is  `f[x] > 0` for `-0.99831 < x < 0 || 0 < x < 1.00031 || 9118.78 < x`.

**II.  With Reduce**

More accurate result one can get with `Reduce`, however we have to distinguish both cases, negative and positive `x`. `Root` objects represent exact solutions and they can be approximated with arbitrary precision.

```
Reduce[ f[x] >= 0 && -10 < x < 0, x]
```

> ```
>  Root[{-2 + E^# #^(-1000)& , 
>   0.9983099725543262365055865819379487315199127992223004795015`33.
>   \60205999129768}] 
>  <= x < 0
> ```

```
 Reduce[ f[x] >= 0 && 0 < x, x]
```

> ```
> 0 < x <= Root[{E^# - 2 #^1000& , 
>                1.00030720720511647868912814809108772742`22.56603416313313}] || 
>     x >= Root[{E^# - 2 #^1000& , 
>                9118.7849974050964063799277928144695659982`27.889302069870084}]
> ```

and rewrite the result with a numeric approximation

```
N[ %% || % ]
```

> ```
> -0.99831 <= x < 0. || 0. < x <= 1.00031 || x >= 9118.78
> ```

Now we are to take a closer look at the behavior around interesting points

```
GraphicsColumn[ 
  Plot[ f[x], #, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
        PlotRange -> {-2.1, 3.2}] & /@ {
         {x, -1, -0.995}, {x, 0.995, 1.009}, {x, 9114, 9123}}]
```

[image]